How to achieve compile-time dispatch via generics?
Recently I've tried to implement compile-time dispatch using generics (example below)
public interface IAbstraction
{
    public void Initialize();
}

public sealed class Implementation : IAbstraction
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
    }
}

public sealed class GenericUsage<T> where T : class, IAbstraction
{
    private readonly T _abstraction;

    public GenericUsage(T abstraction)
    {
        _abstraction = abstraction;
    }

    public void CallAction()
    {
        _abstraction.Initialize();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var genericUsage = new GenericUsage<Implementation>(new Implementation());
    genericUsage.CallAction();
}

As you can see, I've also explicitly used sealed keyword as a signal that there is no chance that the type that will be passed to the constructor will be different from that used in Generic.
On the side of JIT Asm I see no de-virtualization. The call is still happening via vtable.
Is there any chance of implementing compile-time dispatch via generics? Maybe I'm missing something. If not, why the example above doesn't work?

@PoulBak take a look again, there is a sealed keyword for the Implementation class

I meant that at a compile-time known that GenericUsage<Implementation> will receive in the constructor only the Implementation instance and nothing else. And there is no chance that will be passed a descendant from the Implementation class.

And that will be a different generic, through sealed I avoid ambiguous behavior and guarantee that in constructor will be passed an instance of the same type that is used in the generic.
Your suggestion with public sealed class GenericUsage<T> where T : Implementation makes no sense, I want compile-time dispatch using generic, in that case, why do I need generic? I will just write a plane class that is using Implementation, but this isn't what I asked

From this answer, it seems like the jitter treats all reference types in the same way (?). Perhaps using a struct would work?

@Sweeper, good point, but the result is the same

Well then this is just not a feature it seems.

this is very similar to this (still open) github issue ...

There is a 2015 open issue that is very similar to what you try to achieve:
RyuJIT call optimization and aggressive inlining with known generic types
From the comments (2018):

For generics instantiated over ref types we're unlikely to do
devirtualization anytime soon, as the jit only sees the shared
version. This might change down the road, if we somehow enabled
unshared ref type instantiations or started looking into speculative
devirtualization.

The "shared version" is better explained in Shared Generics Design

The idea is that for certain instantiations, the generated code will
almost be identical with the exception of a few instructions, so in
order to reduce the memory footprint, and the amount of time we spend
jitting these generic methods, the runtime will generate a single
special canonical version of the code, which can be used by all
compatible instantiations of the method.
This feature is currently only supported for instantiations over
reference types because they all have the same
size/properties/layout/etc... For instantiations over primitive types
or value types, the runtime will generate separate code bodies for
each instantiation.

If we look at the disassembly (.NET 6 and .NET 7, Debug, x86) it makes sense:
        public void CallAction() 
            {
...
je          ConsoleApp64.GenericUsage`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].CallAction()+01Fh (057C997h)  
call        10045230   
            //callvirt instance void IAbstraction::Initialize()
            _abstraction.Initialize();
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
call        dword ptr [Pointer to: CLRStub[VSD_LookupStub]@d82df850017a042 (0170020h)]  
        }

There is a "canonical" jitted method that is used for every GenericUsage<T>.CallAction() where T is a class.
je          ConsoleApp64.GenericUsage`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]].CallAction()+01Fh (057C997h) 

with the body:
            //callvirt instance void IAbstraction::Initialize()
            _abstraction.Initialize();
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-38h]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ecx+4]  
call        dword ptr [Pointer to: CLRStub[VSD_LookupStub]@d82df850017a042 (0170020h)]  

The JITter cannot devirtualize and insert a direct call to (or inline) Implementation.Initialize() because the same jitted code would be "shared" for GenericUsage<SecondImplementation>.CallAction(), GenericUsage<ThirdImplementation>.CallAction().
As mentioned in the original github issue comment, there needs to be "unshared ref type" instantiations for this to work.
EDIT: Either this or something else was implemented in .NET 8 when T is a sealed class (will edit if somebody comments the exact issue - but maybe Dynamic PGO?) which is visible when we compare a generic with a class and a struct. The struct would normally always get an "unshared" implementation so the JIT can make a faster static dispatch to it. Slightly modified code to test and benchmark:
public interface IAbstraction {
    public int Initialize(int param);
}

public sealed class Implementation : IAbstraction {
    public int Initialize(int param) {
        return param;
    }
}

public struct StructImplementation : IAbstraction {
    public int Initialize(int param) {
        return param;
    }
}

public sealed class GenericUsage<T> where T : IAbstraction {
    private readonly T _abstraction;

    public GenericUsage(T abstraction) {
        _abstraction = abstraction;
    }

    public int CallAction(int param) {
        return _abstraction.Initialize(param);
    }
}

// Benchmark methods
public int TestRef() {
    var genericUsage = new GenericUsage<Implementation>(new Implementation());

    var sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
        sum += genericUsage.CallAction(i);
    }
    
    return sum;

}

public int TestStruct() {
    var genericUsage = new GenericUsage<StructImplementation>(new StructImplementation());

    var sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++) {
        sum += genericUsage.CallAction(i);
    }

    return sum;
}

.NET 6:
Case ResultsGraph    Mean Min Max Range   AllocatedBytesΞΞ OperationsΞΞ    Phase
TestRef     450.70 μs   346.59 μs   637.78 μs   65 % 49  97,280  Complete
TestStruct  85.76 μs    49.76 μs    123.15 μs   86 % 24  819,200 Complete

.NET 7
Case    ResultsGraph    Mean    Min Max Range   AllocatedBytesΞΞ    OperationsΞΞ    Phase
TestRef     434.15 μs   331.40 μs   572.71 μs   56% 49  95,232  Complete
TestStruct  89.63 μs    50.85 μs    119.15 μs   76% 24  819,200 Complete

.NET 8 (sealed T matters):
Case    ResultsGraph    Mean    Min Max Range   AllocatedBytesΞΞ    OperationsΞΞ    Phase
TestRefNonSealed        1.03 ms 626.93 μs   1.34 ms 69% 49  102,400 Complete
TestRef     84.58 μs    57.82 μs    112.69 μs   65% 48  819,200 Complete
TestStruct  63.55 μs    40.90 μs    95.03 μs    85% 24  811,008 Complete

